# What is cakephp's 'maximum depth reached', I got this error while patination with message 'address not found'

Tags: cakephp, pagination

I am new to cakephp and using 2.4 version with bootstrap css.
I have almost finished my project but getting some errors while creating search with pagination.

While pagination in Cakephp, first pages are working fine but last 2-3 pages shows error as the requested address was not found on this server.

tables are below. 
universities, courses, semesters, subjects, units, topics
respectively these models having hasMany relationships from left to right.
e.g. universities hasMany courses, courses hasMany semesters.....

my search actions is as below.

```
public function searchresults() {
        if($this->request->is('post')) {
            $unid=$this->data['University']['universities'];
            $searched =  $this->data['University']['searchtxt'];
            $this->Session->write('Searched.stext',$searched);
            $this->Session->write('Searched.univ',$unid);
        }

            $unid=$this->Session->read('Searched.univ');
            $searched = $this->Session->read('Searched.stext');

            //Create Join to find total numbers of records after search
            $this->Topic->bindModel(array(
                'belongsTo' => array(
                    'Unit' => array(
                                'foreignKey' => false,
                                'type' => 'RIGHT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                'Topic.unit_id = Unit.id' ,
                                )
                            ),
                    'Subject' => array(
                                'foreignKey' => false,
                                'type' => 'RIGHT',
                                'conditions' => array(
                                    'Unit.subject_id = Subject.id',
                                )
                            ),
                    'Semester' => array(
                                'foreignKey'=> false,
                                'type'=>'RIGHT',
                                'conditions' => array (
                                    'Subject.semester_id = Semester.id'
                                )
                            ),  
                    'Course' => array(
                                'foreignKey'=> false,
                                'type'=>'RIGHT',
                                'conditions' => array (
                                    'Semester.course_id = Course.id'
                                )
                            ),
                    'University' => array(
                                'foreignKey'=> false,
                                'type'=>'RIGHT',
                                'conditions' => array (
                                    'Course.university_id = University.id'
                                )
                            )
                )
            ));
            $this->Paginator->settings=array(
                'limit'=>10,
                'page'=>1,
                'conditions' => array('or'=>array(
                    'Topic.name LIKE' => '%'.$searched.'%',
                    'Topic.description LIKE' => '%'.$searched.'%'
                )),
            );
            $data=$this->paginate('Topic');
            //debug($data);
            $this->set('searched',$searched);
            $this->set('sresults',$data);
            $this->set('uni_id',$unid);


    }
```

my view's pagination part code is as below:

```
<div class="row"><!--Pagination links begins -->
                                    <div class="col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-3">
                                    <!-- Shows the next and previous links -->
                                    <ul class="pagination largescreen">
                                    <li class="disabled-page mobileview">
                                        Page <?php echo $this->Paginator->counter(); ?>
                                    </li>   
                                    <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('«', array('tag'=>'li'), null, array('class' => 'disabled-page','tag'=>'li')); ?>
                                    <!-- Shows the page numbers -->
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
                                            'tag'=>'li',
                                            'separator'=>'',
                                            'currentClass'=>'active',
                                            'currentTag'=>'a',
                                            'modulus'=>4

                                        )); 
                                    ?>

                                    <?php echo $this->Paginator->next('»', array('tag'=>'li'), null, array('class' => 'disabled-page','tag'=>'li')); ?>
                                    </ul>
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm smallscreen" style="overflow:auto;">
                                    <li class="disabled-page mobileview">
                                        Page <?php echo $this->Paginator->counter(); ?>
                                    </li>   
                                    <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('«', array('tag'=>'li'), null, array('class' => 'disabled-page','tag'=>'li')); ?>
                                    <!-- Shows the page numbers -->
                                    <?php 
                                        echo $this->Paginator->numbers(array(
                                            'tag'=>'li',
                                            'separator'=>'',
                                            'currentClass'=>'active',
                                            'currentTag'=>'a',
                                            'modulus'=>8

                                        )); 
                                    ?>

                                    <?php echo $this->Paginator->next('»', array('tag'=>'li'), null, array('class' => 'disabled-page','tag'=>'li')); ?>
                                    </ul>
                                    </div>
                            </div><!--Pagination links ends -->
```

Please help as i am stuck after searching a lot about this...